# Burp Suite Logger++ Extension Show Only in-Scope items

Tags: security, penetration-testing, burp, penetration-tools

Logger++ is a great extension to Burp Suite. However, I cannot find a basic solution to my problem. I just want to add a `filter to see only in-scope items` like in the burp's own logger itself. Is there anyone who has a solution for that?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on Logger++ and go to the Options tab in logger++. There you will see Checkmark for In Scope Items Only, click that and clear the previous logs. After that, you will only see the items which are in scope.